# Move constructor orphaning memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, memory-management, move-semantics

I am looking at this answer showing a move constructor:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3109981/997112

```
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

class string
{
    char* data;

public:

    string(const char* p)
    {
        size_t size = strlen(p) + 1;
        data = new char[size];
        memcpy(data, p, size);
    }

    ~string()
    {
        delete[] data;
    }

    string(const string& that)
    {
        size_t size = strlen(that.data) + 1;
        data = new char[size];
        memcpy(data, that.data, size);
    }

};
```

and then a move constructor is introduced:

```
string(string&& that)   // string&& is an rvalue reference to a string
{
    data = that.data;
    that.data = 0;
}
```

If we assign pointer `data` to the value `that.data`, surely this causes a memory leak for the `new char[size]` memory which `data` was originally pointing to? I am confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`data` isn't already pointing at anything because this is the constructor. This is the first thing that happens when the object is created.

When constructing this object, it takes ownership of `that.data` which was allocated by the other object. By assigning `0` to `that.data`, it ensures that the other object won't `delete` the data. Now this object is responsible for doing it, which it will do in its destructor.

Comment: True, which is why the conventional syntax would be `string(string&& that) : data(that.data)` (initializer list).